# NSPasteboard, how to get URL of html content

Tags: html, macos, url, clipboard

My application accepts HTML pasted from clipboard or dragged from a browser.

I am able to get HTML (fragment) successfully:

```
  NSPasteboard *pasteboard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];

  NSString* nstext = [pasteboard stringForType:NSPasteboardTypeHTML];
```

but have no idea of how to get URL of source document.

Tried this:

```
  NSLog(@"url: %@", [NSURL URLFromPasteboard:pasteboard]);
```

but no luck - it reports `url: nil`.

Is it possible in principle?

Just in case, on Windows I can get that URL from one of fields of CF_HTML clipboard format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me. Error checking, etc omitted for brevity:

```
NSPasteboard *pasteboard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
NSData *data = [pasteboard dataForType:@"Apple Web Archive pasteboard type"];
NSDictionary *plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:data
                                                                options:NSPropertyListImmutable
                                                                 format:NULL
                                                                  error:nil];

NSDictionary *values = [plist objectForKey:@"WebMainResource"];
NSString *url = [values objectForKey:@"WebResourceURL"];
```